# Associated primes of a quotient module.

Tags: commutative-algebra, noetherian

> Let $R$ be a Noetherian ring, $M$ a finitely generated $R$-module and $p\in \operatorname{Ass}(M)$. Suppose $x$ is an $M$-regular element and $q$ is a minimal prime over $I=(p,x)$. How can we show that $q\in \operatorname{Ass}(M/xM)$?

Note: Since $q$ is minimal prime over $(p,x)$, we know that in $R_q$, $I_q$ is $qR_q$-primary.

Comment: @YACP comapared to this answer i like your solution, i will accept it if you put it down. But i have found a solution, and i like my solution. The only thing i dont like about it is that i have to use krull's intersection theorem.

Comment: But the solution by youngsu below is quite good too.

Comment: I didn't say that his solution isn't good, but it uses far less elementary tools than you've expected. Anyway, why don't post your solution, too? It would be nice to have more solutions! (I've deleted mine because it was only a hint, and I don't have time to fill in the details.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume to the contrary suppose that $q$ is not associated to $M/xM$. We localize at $q$ to assume that $(R,q)$ is local and $\sqrt{(p,x)} = q$. Since $q$ is not associated to $M/xM$, there exists $y \in q$ such that $x,y$ is an $M$-regular sequence. Observe that $y^l$ is $M/xM$-regular for $l \ge 1$. Therefore, we may assume that $y \in (p,x)$. Write $y = w + ax$ for some $w \in p$ and $a \in R$ and $I = (x,y) = (w,x)$. We show that $w,x$ is an $M$-sequence. Since $\operatorname{depth}(I,M) = 2$, by the statement below we conclude that $H_i(w,x;M) = 0$ for $i > 0$. This implies that $w \in p$ is $M$-regular. This contradicts the assumption $p$ associated to $M$.

> Let $R$ be a Noetherian ring and $I$ an $R$-ideal. Let $x_1,\dots,x_n$ be a generating set for $I$. For a finitely generated $R$-module $M$,
>   $$
> \operatorname{depth}_I(M) = n - \sup \{ i \mid H_i( x_1,\dots,x_n ; M) \neq 0 \}.
> $$
>   Here $H_i ( x_1, \dots, x_n; M)$  denote the ith Koszul homology of $M$ with respect to $x_1,\dots,x_n$.

Comment: Very nice, i learned something in your solution, so i am glad. I will wait an hour before accepting the answer as YACP had posted an answer before and i was waiting to see if there was another solution. It is a pity that you may not get any credit for this as the question was not voted at all, i think this is a really nice problem in commutative algebra.

Comment: @user114539: No worries. I am pretty sure that there are several other ways to see this. Interesting exercise!

Answer (score 0):

I dont feel comfortable answering my own question but i am sketching a solution as I was asked to do so above. As seen in the solution by Youngsu and by YACP, we may assume that $(R,m)$ is a Noetherian local ring and $m$ is minimal over $(p,x)$. As $p\in \operatorname{Ass}M$, $p=(0:y)$ for some $0\neq y\in M$. By Krull's Intersection theorem there exists a $r$ such that $y\in x^rM\setminus x^{r+1}M$. Thus $y=x^ra$ for some $a\in M\setminus xM$. Since $x$ is $M$ regular, it follows that $p=(0:a)$. Since $p\in \operatorname{Ass}M$, we have the following natural composite map, say $f$, $Ra\cong R/p\subseteq M\to M/xM$. Note that $Im(f)\neq 0$. Observe that $Im(f)\cong R/(p,x)$ which is of finite length. Thus $m\in Ass(Im(f))\subseteq Ass(M/xM)$.

Comment: $y\ne 0$ should be said!

Comment: Is it true that $Im(f)\cong R/(p,x)$? I can see only a surjection $R/(p,x)\to Im(f)$ (which also sustains your argument, but...).

Comment: $Im(f)\cong aR+xM/xM\cong aR/{aR\cap xM}\cong Ra/xRa\cong R/(p,x)$? No?

Comment: I don't know! Why $aR\cap xM=xRa$ (or why they are isomorphic, as you have written)? In fact, I don't even understand what $xRa$ means: is it the submodule $(Rx)a$? Not to mention the last isomorphism that is beyond my understanding.

Comment: $N:=Ra$ is the cyclic submodule of $M$ generated by $a$. Now take $xN$ like $xM$, perhaps it is bad notation.

Comment: You are right, i somehow thought that there was an equality $xM\cap N= xN$, but cant see it now. But $xN\subseteq xM\cap N$, which gives the surjection you indicate above.